# UPDATE : Most Samsung Androids have "Settings" button too in soft keyboard. How to intercept or disable that?

Tags: android

I have a full screen activity with a ExitText. When edit text is clicked(gets focus) a softkeyboard shows up.

Now, on some samsung android phones(atleast two that I have used), the keypad also has a small "Settings" button which will close your activity and take you to phone's system settings button.

I want to intercept when a user click's this "Settings" soft button and then take some decision before my activity gets pushed back to the stack.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

**EDIT**

I know that in normal circumstance its a bad user experience and should be avoided. However, I am more interested in the solution (technology side). I am not going to launch an app in the market with such a thing for regular user, so please dont comment saying I should not do this.

I know that developers put such comments in the benefit of the users who are still learning but in some cases, "Its more about HOW to do it?". This scenario is just one of them. Hope nobody takes what I said in a wrong sense. Thnx!

Comment: Why do you think you should be able to do this? I'd be pretty upset, as a user.

Comment: I know that it would be a bad user experience but this is a custom requirement by the user. Think it that way. Now, lets assume that this WILL NOT upset the user because of this special case, is there a solution?

Comment: So, it's a bad user experience, but also a custom user requirement? Are you sure you don't mean a custom *client* requirement?

Comment: Yup, thats what I meant.

Comment: My advice: try to talk your client out of a corrosive requirement.

Comment: I am more interested in the solution. Thanks for the advice anyway!

Comment: I am trying to do a similar thing. My app requires you to logout whenever the activity enters the background for security reasons. When the user enters the keyboard settings activity, the app goes to the background and logs out the user.

Now I would like to be able to intercept this event, and display a confirmation dialog, such as "Are you sure you wish to view your keyboard settings, this will result in you becoming logged out."

So I agree with Vikas, there are times when it could be useful to override this button.

Comment: Any update for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use android:inputType="number" in the layout of the activity and the soft keyboard either will not have the Settings key or it will be disabled. I implemented it and tested it on a samsung phone(2.3.6) and the solution works!