# Disabling settings button on keyboard in app

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Is it possible to completely disable the settings key from the softkeyboard for an android app?

The button i want to disable is the second button on the left-bottom in the image:

[Example](https://www.google.nl/search?q=android+soft+keyboard+settings&es_sm=94&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=NrdwU7HBE8PkOujmgIgK&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1215&bih=938#q=aosp+keyboard&tbm=isch&facrc=_&imgrc=y5_z6PrxoJJjFM%253A%3BXCjnoC7Qnk0KFM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fimg651.imageshack.us%252Fimg651%252F8934%252Fscreenshot2013011721194.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fforum.xda-developers.com%252Fshowthread.php%253Ft%253D1965768%3B800%3B589)

Now i have something like this:

```
userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
userName.setOnKeyListener(this);
password.setOnKeyListener(this);

public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

switch (v.getId()) {
     case R.id.txt_name:
     if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
     && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SETTINGS)) {
        mUserName = userName.getText().toString();
        if (mUserName.equals("")) {
           Toast.makeText(this, "Enter user name...",
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     } else
     password.requestFocus();
     break
  }
}
```

unfortunately this code wont detect the settings key.

Comment: But what's your problem with that settings button ?

Comment: I think the answer is no. There are a lot of different implementation of keyboards and you can do that for some of these. But you can't be sure, that it will work for all implementations.

Comment: I am creating a kiosk tablet, which can only run my app.
I'm creating a custom rom, so there is only 1 keyboard, no option to install another.

Comment: Create your own custom keyboard.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UPDATE : Most Samsung Androids have "Settings" button too in soft keyboard. How to intercept or disable that?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135429/update-most-samsung-androids-have-settings-button-too-in-soft-keyboard-how)

Comment: Any update for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to completely disable the settings key from the softkeyboard for an android app?

You can write your own input method editor (or modify the code for an existing one) that does not have this button. Putting this as the default keyboard in your custom ROM would then achieve your objective.

An SDK app, however, cannot disable this button or otherwise control the behavior of an input method editor in this fashion.

Answer (score 0):

try `onKeyDown` in place of `onKey` . in your code for exemple :

```
@Override  
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
switch (v.getId()) {
     case R.id.txt_name:
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SETTINGS) {        
        mUserName = userName.getText().toString();
        if (mUserName.equals("")) {
           Toast.makeText(this, "Enter user name...",
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     } else
     password.requestFocus();
     break
  }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry for you. so there is no possibility to override the setting Key ?